# Moving from .css to jQuery css(), not working when elements are added on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jcrop

Before you comment about this i know that is better to have a separate CSS file for maintainability purposes. But i need to use **Jcrop plugin without any CSS or image**, all should be embedded in a single `croppable.js` file.

The **problem** is: css is not applied to the **elements added on the fly by Jcrop** (some `divs` with `.jcrop-vline`, `.jcrop-hline` and other classes).

What i did: i removed original `jquery.Jcrop.css` file and base64 encoded `Jcrop.gif` inside original Jcrop the package. The resulting `croppable.js` is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cropborder64 = "data:image/gif;base64,dasn/%£"; // Crop image (cutted)

    $(".jcrop-holder").css({"text-align" : "left"});

    $(".jcrop-vline, .jcrop-hline").css({
        "font-size"  : "0px",
        "position"   : "absolute",
        "background" : "white url(" + cropborder64 + ") top left repeat",
        "height"     : "100%",
        "width"      : "1px !important"
    });

    $(".jcrop-vline.right").css({ "right" : "0px" });
    $(".jcrop-hline.bottom").css({ "bottom" : "0px" });

    $(".jcrop-handle").css({
        "font-size"        : "1px",
        "width"            : "7px !important",
        "height"           : "7px !important",
        "border"           : "1px #eee solid",
        "background-color" : "#333"
    });

    $(".jcrop-tracker").css({ "width"  : "100%", "height" : "100%" });
    $(".custom.jcrop-vline, .custom.jcrop-hline").css({
        "background" : "yellow"
    });

    $(".custom.jcrop-handle").css({
        "border-color"          : "black",
        "background-color"      : "#C7BB00",
        "-moz-border-radius"    : "3px",
        "-webkit-border-radius" : "3px"
    });
}); // End of document.ready
```

And this is how i use it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/croppable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('img.crop').each(function() {
                    $(this).Jcrop();
                });
            }); // End of document.ready
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="crop" src="../images/test.jpg" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `<style />`-tag and adding that to the document? This would get you at least rid of all the fixed css. Also it would affect generated elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to place everything in a function that is called each time you add an element.

Edit:

Something like that :

```
$(function() {
    var cropborder64 = "data:image/gif;base64,dasn/%£";

    function reload(){

        $(".jcrop-holder").css({"text-align" : "left"});

        $(".jcrop-vline, .jcrop-hline").css({
            "font-size"  : "0px",
            "position"   : "absolute",
            "background" : "white url(" + cropborder64 + ") top left repeat",
            "height"     : "100%",
            "width"      : "1px !important"
        });

        $(".jcrop-vline.right").css({ "right" : "0px" });
        $(".jcrop-hline.bottom").css({ "bottom" : "0px" });

        $(".jcrop-handle").css({
            "font-size"        : "1px",
            "width"            : "7px !important",
            "height"           : "7px !important",
            "border"           : "1px #eee solid",
            "background-color" : "#333"
        });

        $(".jcrop-tracker").css({ "width"  : "100%", "height" : "100%" });
        $(".custom.jcrop-vline, .custom.jcrop-hline").css({
            "background" : "yellow"
        });

        $(".custom.jcrop-handle").css({
            "border-color"          : "black",
            "background-color"      : "#C7BB00",
            "-moz-border-radius"    : "3px",
            "-webkit-border-radius" : "3px"
        });

    }
    reload();

    $('#addNewElementButton').on({
        click: function(){
            $('.crop').append('<img class="crop" src="../images/test.jpg" alt="" />');
            reload();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you post some code example and explain better why my solution is not working?

Comment: Your JS is called only once, so your CSS are applied at the beginning, when you add an element you need to call your JS another time to put your css to that new element. I will edit my message with an example.